# Rails - Constants Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a need for a model(?) on my app which basically contains a status of another entity.  In the entity I want to store the id of the status, but in my app, the view is talking in terms of a nice word description.  For instance, 1=New, 2=Used etc etc.

How can I go about implementing this in the best way that means I can easily set and retrieve this status column without repeating myself?

Ultimately I would like something like

```
Foo.status = 'New'  (actually sets value to 1)
```

and

```
Foo.status  (returns 'New', but stores 1)
```

Am I even thinking about this in the right way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can code a custom writer method:

```
STATUS_VALUES = { 1 => 'new', 2 => 'modified', 3 => 'deleted' }

class Foo
  attr_reader :status_id

  def status
    STATUS_VALUES[@status_id]
  end

  def status=(new_value)
    @status_id = STATUS_VALUES.invert[new_value]
    new_value
  end
end
```

For example, the following program:

```
foo_1 = Foo.new

foo_1.status = 'new'
puts "status: #{foo_1.status}"
puts "status_id: #{foo_1.status_id}"

foo_1.status = 'deleted'
puts "status: #{foo_1.status}"
puts "status_id: #{foo_1.status_id}"
```

outputs:

```
status: new
status_id: 1
status: deleted
status_id: 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd just go ahead and use symbols, something like

```
Foo.status = :new
```

They're basically immutable strings, meaning that no matter how many times you use the same symbol in your code, it's still one object in memory:

```
>> :new.object_id
=> 33538
>> :new.object_id
=> 33538
>> "new".object_id
=> 9035250
>> "new".object_id
=> 9029510 # <- Different object_id
```

Comment: Heh, Ruby seems to have found quite a lot of Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be using constants

```
module MyConstants
  New  = 1
  Used = 2
end
```

Then you can use them like this

```
Foo.status = MyConstants::New
```

or even like this if you're carefull about namespace polution

```
include MyConstants
Foo.status = New
```

On another thought, maybe you want to use a [state machine](http://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/tree/master).

Comment: Not exactly what he wanted, I think, since "New" (the string) is different than MyConstants:New (the object).